# Automatic layout of relational graph

Tags: java, algorithm, layout, graph

I'm parsing a file with information about the relationship between blocks. The file gives my info like:

```
a b
a d
b c
```

And this corresponds to an image looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8wyS.gif) (the numbers can be ignored, they are the weight of the blocks).

So right letter, like `b` on the first row, means that `a`stands atop of it.

My question is, how would I go about trying to programatically create images like these?

I'm currently implementing this in Java, but I'm mostly looking for higher level information about the problem domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you work with graphs and use Java I'd recommed to take a look at [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/). First convert your graph to a Gephi-compartible format (e.g. gexf) and see if Gephi saticfied your requirements. Then  use Gephi API/libraries to solve your tasks.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at that! Looks like something I'm looking for.